# DeleteMapping Spring Boot Freemarker, не получается удалить

Tags: java, spring, delete

Есть на странице лист объектов, хочу добавить кнопку удалить.
Нахожу объект по айди(хотя вопрос зачем, я же кнопку жму по тому объекту, который имеет уже айдишник).

```
@DeleteMapping("/notes/{id}")
    public String deleteNote(@PathVariable Long id, Model model
    ) {
        Note note = noteRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid note Id" + id));
        noteRepository.delete(note);
        model.addAttribute("noteDelete", note);
        return "notes";
    }
```

notes.ftl:

```
<#list notes as note>
    <p>${note.id}. Title:${note.title} Read<a href="/notes/${note.id}">more</a></p>
    <form action="/notes/${noteDelete.id}">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete">
    </form>
<#else>
    <p>Notes not found</p>
</#list>
```

Как правильно тут удалить? В чем ошибка

Comment: Так а в чем ошибка? А так навскидку, используйте сразу deleteById(ID id) и не возвращайте удаленный элемент обратно в модели

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko так я пытался и так и так)
например сейчас ошибка failed to convert String to Long for input : "тут текст объекта поля text", хотя не понимаю причем тут он
не хочет удалять, просто открывает мне страницу с /notes/id (конкретный объект), тоесть у меня есть урл с выводом конкретного объекта по айди. Но не удаляет

Comment: Ну я хз. Ничего не понятно. И почему не так  <form action="/notes/${note.id}" method="DELETE">? Откуда этот ноутДелете?

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko model.addAttribute("noteDelete", note);

Answer (score 0):

@DeleteMapping принимает запросы с методом DELETE. Не указывая атрибута method в теге form, по умолчанию методом запроса будет GET. НО, в атрибуте method можно указать только GET и POST. Это означает, что данный запрос нужно отправлять с помощью JavaScript (XMLHttpRequest или Fetch API).

Comment: почему же тогда в CRUD примерах Spring Boot Thymleaf например там просто такие формочки

Comment: @ekstra777 скорее всего там используют только `@GetMapping` и `@PostMapping`

Answer (score 0):

```
@PostMapping("/notes/{id}")
    public String deleteNote(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model
    ) {
        Note note = noteRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid note Id" + id));
        noteRepository.delete(note);
        model.addAttribute("noteDelete", note);
        return "redirect:/notes";
    }


notes.ftl:
<#list notes as note>
    <p>${note.id}. Title:${note.title} Read<a href="/notes/${note.id}">more</a></p>
    <form action="/notes/${noteDelete.id}" method="post"> 
        <input type="submit" value="Delete">
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    </form>
<#else>
    <p>Notes not found</p>
</#list>
```